# Kotlin Error: Dagger does not support injection into private fields

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I use in kotlin activity ViewPager and I want in Kotlin Fragment use the dagger injection. I have got Error: Dagger does not support injection into private fields.
In Java Fragment the dagger injection work.
Why can i not inject dagger in kotlin faragment ?

in my kotlin activity

```
mPagerAdapter = object : FragmentPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager) {

        private val mFragments = arrayOf(KotlinFragment(), JavaFragment())
        private val mFragmentNames = arrayOf(getString(R.string.cashdocuments), getString(R.string.action_absmysql))

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return mFragments[position]
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mFragments.size
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
            return mFragmentNames[position]
        }
    }
```

my kotlin fragment

```
class KotlinFragment : Fragment()  {


@Inject
internal var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    (activity.application as SamfantozziApp).dgaeacomponent().inject(this)

}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    val rootView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.activity_absserver, container, false)

    return rootView
}

}
```

messages gradle build

[image]

Comment: Its a shortcoming of Dagger in general-  it can't access private fields.  Doing so would require reflection and would be impossible to do at compile time like Dagger prefers.  Doing so at run time would cost loading time to do reflective calls.  So it just doesn't support it at all.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Accidentally I came across to my own answer and have to confess, that in fact it isn't working (at least for my use-case). Please consider [Avilio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187657/kotlin-error-dagger-does-not-support-injection-into-private-fields/48554204#48554204) which worked for me also: substitute `internal` with `lateinit`.

---

### Old answer

Remove `internal` modifier. Dagger needs at least package-private access in order to access annotated field. In Kotlin `internal` modifier is **not** a substitution for Java's package-private access modifier.

For detailed explanation of differences between modifiers in Java and Kotlin refer to Fragmented podcast's [episode #101](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/101/) - *"Learning Kotlin – visibility modifiers, internal modifier, modules"*, as well as the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html).

Comment: I have posted Gradle Build Messages. I do not understand what private field is problem.

Comment: The error message has been changed to a different one, which differs from your original question. Refer to other similar questions.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have changed my question back to original.

Comment: @azizbekian I have removed internal modifier, then too I am getting this error.

Comment: Why remove `internal`? It works perfectly well with Dagger. By omitting a visibility modifier you're making your fields public and breaking encapsulation.

Answer (score 74):

You have mistake here:

```
    @Inject
internal var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
```

This looks like you added `@Inject` annotation to the `KotlinFragment` class

Please change it to this and it will work:

```
var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
        @Inject set
```

Here is the link to the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I may add that in case of DI, it may be useful to annotate the setter parameter. For example if you want to inject two `String` and you differentiate them with `@Qualifier` annotation classes, the setter needs to have that information: `@Inject set(@CustomAnnotation param) { field = param }`.

Comment: You can also: `@set:Inject var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null`

Answer (score 45):

As simple you can do this, change this line

```
@Inject
internal var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
```

To

```
@set:Inject
internal var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
```

this work like charm  in my case.

Comment: Thanks! This work for me to inject primitive type like integer.

Comment: Nice.Works like charm.Thank you!

Answer (score 37):

I had the same error, even upon removing the internal keyword. So I replaced **internal** with **lateinit** and it worked.

Comment: Note that lateinit doesn't allow nullable type (? type). For nullable field, please make use of Provider or Lazy. The wrapped type can be nullable it.

Comment: This seems very odd, why does this work? Dagger's complaining about the `var` being `private` (which it isn't), and making it `lateinit` fixes that? Why?

Answer (score 12):

```
@Inject
lateinit var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

Also, this worked for me as well for late initialization variable

Answer (score 8):

I followed the above advise of not making the field internal. But, that was not enough.  Kapt still converting the var to private during compilation.

I had to add the `@JvmField` annotation to make it behave better.

The answer I found was here: 
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kapt-converting-public-fields-to-private-during-compilation/11757

Answer (score 5):

```
@Inject
internal var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
```

Just change this to

```
@Inject
lateinit var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

P.S. You can't use lateinit with nullables.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `internal` modifier. And I also had to declare `lateinit` and remove the Optional.

Answer (score 4):

In My case, I changed

```
@Inject
var locationDBWrapper: LocationDBWrapper? = null
```

to

```
@Inject
lateinit var locationDBWrapper: LocationDBWrapper
```

Issue got resolved

Comment: While this resolves the issue and thus the +1, if any still wants to be able to define the field as nullable, do this (summary: add @JvmField annotation with nullable declaration): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310196/kotlin-and-dagger-can-i-use-inject-to-an-object-still-make-it-nullable-optiona

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined `fun inject(fragment: KotlinFragment)` in your `ApplicationComponent`? Because it looks like your error message is saying exactly that.

EDIT: maybe you haven't provided `SharedPreferences` in your Module like this:

```
@Module
public class AndroidModule {
    private final TimrApplication application;

    public AndroidModule(TimrApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences(){
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. I have defined KotlinFragment in my DgAeaComponent.java Problem is with definition of var mSharedPreferences in my KotlinFragment.kt

Comment: I added the provide method for the `SharedPreferences` like you should have defined in any of your modules which is used in a Component like this: `@Component(modules = AndroidModule.class)`

Comment: I provide method for the SharedPreferences in my Module. The problem was with declaration of  var mSharedPreferences in my KotlinFragment.kt. It has to be @Inject lateinit var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences Edit your answer i would like to check.

Answer (score 1):

After updating to Android Studio 3.5, most of the answers don't work. The consolidated solution is :

**1. If you want to use `lateinit`:**

```
@Inject lateinit var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

**2. If you don't want to use `lateinit`:**

```
var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
    @Inject set(value) {
       field = value
}
```

**OR**

```
@Inject
@JvmField
var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

**NOTE: These methods don't work anymore. You get the error `not a valid name: <set-?>Provide`**

```
@set:Inject
var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
```

```
var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null 
    @Inject set
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make injected vars private, but you can make them protected, which is effectively the same in a final class (and in Kotlin classes are final by default unless you use the "open" modifier). Also, use lateinit modifier like it has been said already.

```
@Inject
protected lateinit var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
```

If your class is not open, this might produce a warning in Android Studio saying "'protected' visibility is effectively 'private' in a final class" - you can just suppress that with:

```
@Suppress("ProtectedInFinal")
```