# Dagger Nullable - Getting issues with Nullable while creating dagger bindings

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Getting [Dagger/Nullable] error while using `@Inject` for `Drawable` field.

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
object AppModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun provideRequestOptions() = RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.white_background)
            .error(R.drawable.white_background)

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun provideGlideInstance(application: Application, requestOptions: RequestOptions) =
            Glide.with(application).setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun provideAppDrawable(application: Application) =
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(application, R.drawable.logo)
}
```

This is my activity where I am consuming the Drawable.

AuthActivity

```
class AuthActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    object Constants {
        const val TAG = "AuthActivity"
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var drawableLogo: Drawable

    @Inject
    lateinit var requestManager: RequestManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)
        setLogo()
    }

    fun setLogo() = requestManager.load(drawableLogo).into(loginLogo)
}
```

Error that I am getting is :-

```
/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/di/AppComponent.java:7: error: [Dagger/Nullable] android.graphics.drawable.Drawable is not nullable, but is being provided by @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable @Provides android.graphics.drawable.Drawable com.example.di.AppModule.provideAppDrawable(android.app.Application)
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.example.BaseApplication> {
                ^
      android.graphics.drawable.Drawable is injected at
          com.example.AuthActivity.drawableLogo
      com.example.AuthActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.example.di.AppComponent → com.example.di.ActivityBuildersModule_ContributeAuthActivity$app_debug.AuthActivitySubcomponent]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I am not sure what exactly is the issue here. Can someone help.

Comment: `fun provideAppDrawable(application: Application): Drawable?`

Comment: then you can't use lateinit with nullable types.

Comment: [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310196/kotlin-and-dagger-can-i-use-inject-to-an-object-still-make-it-nullable-optiona)?

Comment: it gives an error that lateinit can't used for nullable types.

Comment: did you check the link ?

Comment: Yes it helped. thanks a lot. can you also explain what if I use something like is also working

`@set:Inject
    internal var drawableLogo: Drawable? = null` what's actually happening here?

Comment: Handle the null case from provider method and return a non null Drawable.